# How to write a web api of mvc 5 login method

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Hi I'm writing web API's for my app in web API controller. I'm using this format to write them,

```
// GET: api/ParentsApi/GetSession
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]

public string GetSession()
        {
            var session = db.AspNetSessions.Select(x=> new { x.SessionName , x.Id}).ToList();

            var javaScriptSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            string jsonString = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(session);

            return jsonString;
        }
```

It returns me the required data in json format.

Now i want the same for Login method too, I copied the login method from accounts controller and pasted it in my API controller with some modifications.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            SEA_DatabaseEntities db = new SEA_DatabaseEntities();

            LoginViewModel model = new LoginViewModel();
            model.UserName = UserName;
            model.Password = Password;
            model.RememberMe = false;

            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            LoginUser login = new LoginUser();

            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:

                    var userID = SignInManager.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity.GetUserId();

                    var Name = db.AspNetUsers.Where(x => x.Id == userID).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault();
                    login.Id = userID;
                    login.Name = Name;
                    login.Message = "Login Success";
                    if (UserManager.IsInRole(userID, "Teacher"))
                    {
                        login.Role = "Teacher";
                    }
                    else if (UserManager.IsInRole(userID, "Student"))
                    {
                        login.Role = "Student";
                    }

                    var javaScriptSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                    string jsonString = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(login);

                    return jsonString;

                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    login.Message = "Invalid login attempt.";

                    var javaScriptSerializer1 = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                    string jsonString1 = javaScriptSerializer1.Serialize(login);

                    return jsonString1;

                default:
                    login.Message = "Invalid login attempt.";
                    var javaScriptSerializer2 = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                    string jsonString2 = javaScriptSerializer2.Serialize(login);

                    return jsonString2;
            }
        }
```

here is my LoginUser class code

```
public class LoginUser
        {
            public string Id { set; get; }
            public string Name { set; get; }
            public string Role { set; get; }
            public string Message { set; get; }

        }
```

Now Its giving me error on `UserManager` and `SignInManager` that I have to use generic type of both of them like `UserManager<TUser, TKey>` but there is nothing like this in accounts controller, in potential fixes studio is suggesting me to create a new class of `UserManager` and `SignInManager` under `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` namespaces. I've already included them in start of my controller.

And last `async Task<ActionResult>` is not allow me to return a string having json data in it, I thought to pass it to a route using `RedirectToRoute` but I have no idea how to do this,

I'm stuck here very badly and don't know what should I do.

Comment: Well first of all, you are returning a `string`, not an `ActionResult`, so change `public async Task<ActionResult>` to `public async Task<string>`

Comment: but its still showing me error in usermanager and signmanager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the SignInManager and UserManager by adding this code

```
private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
{
    get
    {
        return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _signInManager = value;
    }
}

public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

Now login api is working perfectly